# What is the Command to create Working-Set in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, command-line-arguments, working-set

I'm working on script which create workspace and imports multiple project using Eclipse command line arguments
Now I want to create working sets with imported projects using command line arguments.
So that I can have compete script which will create workspace + import projects + create working sets + build entire project for each working set configuration

I'm not able to find command to create working set in eclipse, need guidance on this.

your little effort is appreciated.

EDIT 1: I have found this command which will create a workspace or open existing one and import all project to IDE without opening IDE ( HEADLESS )

```
eclipse -nosplash -data workspace -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -importAll core -importAll edge -build
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'command'? Are you asking about the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` command extension point?

Comment: No, I mean by 'Command', a Command to launch eclipse using script file( .batch ).
i.e. eclipse -nosplash -data workspace

Comment: There is no command line option.